# encodeURIComponent encodes differently, depending on environment

Tags: javascript

I am passing an object via the url using:

```
encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(myObject))
```

"ä" is encoded as "%C3%A4" on my local server.
Unfortunately it is encoded as "a%CC%88" on the webserver.

Which breaks my app because it is part of the name of a database field which isn't found when wrong encoded. And I can't control that there are no ä's in field names because the app allows users to upload their own data.

How can I make sure that "ä" is always encoded correctly?

---

SORRY. To make this clear: The encoding happens both times client-side in the browser. But when the web-app is served from the webserver the "ä" is encoded as "%C3%A4" instead of "a%CC%88" (I've tested both in the same chrome browser)

---

Thanks for all your help. It got me to dig deeper:

I have code that runs on an event. It loops through checkboxes and creates an array of objects containing (also) the field names. The code gets the field names from an attribute named "feld" of the checkbox:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input class="feld_waehlen" type="checkbox" dstyp="Taxonomie" datensammlung="SISF Index 2 (2005)" feld="Artname vollständig">Artname vollständig
  </label>
</div>
```

running this code:

```
console.log("this.getAttribute('feld') = " + this.getAttribute('feld'));
```

gives as expected: $(this).attr('feld') = Artname vollständig

If while looping, I run:

```
console.log('encodeURIComponent("Artname vollständig") = ' + encodeURIComponent("Artname vollständig"));
```

the answer is correct: encodeURIComponent("Artname vollständig") = Artname%20vollst%C3%A4ndig

But if I run:

```
console.log("encodeURIComponent(this.getAttribute('feld')) = " + encodeURIComponent(this.getAttribute('feld')));
```

the answer is: encodeURIComponent(this.getAttribute('feld')) = Artname%20vollsta%CC%88ndig

This happens all in the browser. But the issue only appears, when the web-app is served from the webserver (a couchapp running on cloudant.com).

How can it be that the method "getAttribute" returns a different encoding?

Comment: what is your server-side language?

Comment: Using a diacritic in a database column name is asking for trouble in the first place IMHO.

Comment: Seems like it may be a UTF-8 issue.  @jasonsylvia's question is spot on.  Your environments may be set to different languages.

Comment: Are you sure that character is `ä` (`\u00e4`) and not `a\u0308`?

Comment: @jasonslyvia: Actually this does not run on the server but client-side, in the browser (chrome). I can't understand why the issue only occurs when the code that runs in the browser is served by the webserver though instead of by my local computer

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Yeah, if this were a relational database I would have tried all I could to prevent users from creating field names with an ä (or similar). I'm working with couchdb though and the field names are json names, so this didn't seem so problematic to me. Anyway, the data itself is also transported over http (that's how couchdb works) and as this data is all in German, it would be extremely hard to prevent this type of characters from appearing...

Comment: @Bergi: yes, I'm sure that it's an "ä". But maybe I miss the point. I'm sure that it's an "ä" in the json inside couchdb

Comment: @jasonslyvia: There is code that runs server-side - a couchdb list-function in javascript that reads the via url requested field names and delivers a .csv download of these fields. But as mentioned, the encoding happens client-side in the browser

Comment: what's your webpage encoding when served from web server?

Comment: @jasonslyvia: 
Not knowing how exactly to check, here is a large part of the header:  

Request Headers  
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8  
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch  
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4  

Response Headers  
Accept-Ranges:none  
Cache-Control:must-revalidate  
Content-Encoding:gzip  
Content-Type:text/html  
Server:CouchDB/1.0.2 (Erlang OTP/R14B)

Comment: seems like erlang server, can you manage to add a `Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8` header when your server send responses

Comment: @jasonslyvia: I know nearly nothing about servers and manipulating headers. In this case couchdb is serving the data itself but the couchapp is on cloudant.com so I don't even know where to look. Will ask in the couchapp mailing list. Thanks a lot for your pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a follow up in case somebody runs into this issue later.

It seems to be unique to cloudant.com where my couchapp was hosted.

This is the answer I got from their very helpful support:

---

OK - I think I've found the culprit. The issue is that, due to internal optimisations (which are not present in CouchDB), the form of unicode strings can get changed. In this case, ä is represented as:

U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A character
U+0308 COMBINING DIAERESIS character (̈)

instead of

U+00E4 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS character (ä)

Both are semantically equivalent, so the fix is to normalize your unicode strings before comparison. Unfortunately, JavaScript has no built-in unicode normalization, but you can use a library such ashttps://github.com/walling/unorm.

---

It's not an issue for me any more as I changed to a virtual server running on digitalocean.com with vanilla couchdb (and am very happy with it).

But I do think this could hit others developing couchapps in German or other languages needing utf8 and hosting them on cloudant.com

Thanks for your great help.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

The following code has been tested on Chrome 29 OS X, IE 8 Windows XP.

```
encodeURIComponent("ä") //%C3%A4"
decodeURIComponent("%C3%A4") //ä
```

so basically "%C3%A4" should be the expected output.

I think the issue here might be `encodeURIComponent` require a `UTF-8` encoding while your server-side language returns something other than this.

[encodeURICompoent - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: thanks for your help, I very much appreciate it! Please have a look at the extended question